# Gmail conversation sender

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I like conversation grouping very much, but there is one problem that bothers me quite often: in email list view the sender shown is always the sender of the first message in conversation while I would prefer to see the sender of the latest message in the conversation in email list view.

In the example on screenshot you see that Andrey S is specified as the sender while the sender of the latest email in this conversation was other person. My workflow is usual to "process" (reply, do something at the 3rd party resource) email and archive the conversation and when there is new message in this conversation it appears back in my inbox and I would prefer to know who had written that new message straight from Inbox view. Do you know if there is any setting/plugin that would help me?

[image]

Comment: When a conversation has messages from 2 or more senders, the senders names are shown by commas or `..` and some will be hidden if they are too many but the sender of the last message will be shown.

Comment: @Rubén I've understood what the problem is. Those are emails from issue tracking system and it sends all emails with from field "UserFirstName UserLastName <no_reply@domain.com>" where UserFirstName and UserLastName are actual user's first and last name. And it seems that gmail treats those emails as they are from the same sender.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I also experience this annoyance, and have looked into it.  To answer your question, there is no setting which will fix this.

It normally works well, but on threads where the senders are using the same email address (but different email "Names"), Google has decided to interpret them as all the same sender, and just uses the first "Name" field from that sender in the thread.

I recommend you, me, and others who have noticed the same usability bug, submit feedback to Google, and maybe they will change it in the future:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213
https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/